# White screen appears on orientation changes in Android using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-orientation, compose-recomposition

[image]

Hi all. I am facing an issue with my app. I am creating an app with Jetpack compose and on orientation changes the activity is recreating and before rotation the app goes in the white screen mode for 1-2 seconds. I know this is due to recomposition and I have tried putting every values in viewmodel + rememberSaveable but still I am facing this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you please share minimum code so It can be traced.

Comment: It depends of what is the UI. if it requires to drawn hundred of thousand lines in a Canvas, it could be normal.....
Without knowing anythings it's hard to tell you something.